# Call child class's overriden function from parent class reference to child class

Tags: c++, overriding

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "this is A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "this is B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A obj = B();
    obj.foo();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The desired output is `this is B`, but I am getting `this is A`. It works when `obj` is `A*`, but is there a way to get `this is B` while keeping `obj` `A`?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: what is this ```A obj = B();``` ?

Comment: @Mayur Oh, I understand it now. It creates `A` and converts `B()` into it.